Could not find or load main class GUI error in Java Swing
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GUI {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    
    frame.setSize(600, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

Error:
Could not find or load main class GUI
a frame with position'

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/18093928/642706

There's no reason to find the main class here because it never work.
